Dynamic graph filtering by selected measure in Power BI
I want to create a dynamic graph (or tooltip) that filter data by selected measure. I’ll give an example:
I created two measures: "€" & "num_orders". I want to create a chart (or a tooltip) that displays data based on the selected measure. If I select "€", the chart should show something like:

However, if I select "num_orders", the graph should display "num_orders" like:

I'm trying but I don't find the way to get this result. ¿Parameters? ¿SWITCH? Nothing works for m
